# glGetAttribLocation() returns -1 on the position attribute of the vertex shader

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, sdl, glad

I'm making an OpenGL program.  However, whenever I run it, the "vertexIn" attribute of the shader returns negative when getting its location. I've searched several stack overflow posts as well as docs and other websites. Still, I could not find any reason as to why vertexIn returns negative when OpenGL tries to get its location, given that in other working examples, it is used in the same way I use it.

Edited the post to have more code in main so it's able to be reproduced.

Main.cpp

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "Header Files/Shader.h"

Shader shader;
bool isAppRunning{ true };
SDL_Window* window{ nullptr };
SDL_GLContext context{ nullptr };
GLuint VAO{ 0 };
GLuint EBO{ 0 };
GLuint vertexVBO{ 0 };
GLuint colorVBO{ 0 };

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO | SDL_INIT_EVENTS) == -1)
    {
        std::cout << "SDL did not initialize properly." << std::endl;
    }

    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_COMPATIBILITY);

    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 6);

    window = SDL_CreateWindow("OpenGL Project", 320, 180, 1280, 720, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL | SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE);

    if (!window)
    {
        std::cout << "OpenGL Window was not created properly." << std::endl;
    }

    context = SDL_GL_CreateContext(window);

    if (!context)
    {

        std::cout << "OpenGL context could not be created properly! The context is either invalid or not supported by your graphics card! Please try on Another PC!" << std::endl;
    }

    if (!gladLoaderLoadGL())
    {
        std::cout << "Error loading OpenGl extensions." << std::endl;
    }

    Shader::Initialize();

    shader.Create("../OpenGl/Shader Files/Shader.vert", "../OpenGl/Shader Files/Shader.frag");
    shader.Use();

    GLfloat vertices[] = { -0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,
                            0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,
                            0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
                           -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f };

    GLfloat colours[] = { 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
                         0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
                         0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
                         0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f };

    GLuint indices[] = { 0, 1, 3,
                         3, 1, 2 };

    auto vertexAttributeID = shader.GetAttributeID("vertexIn");
    auto colourAttributeID = shader.GetAttributeID("colorIn");

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &vertexVBO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &colorVBO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &EBO);

    glBindVertexArray(VAO);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexVBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glVertexAttribPointer(vertexAttributeID, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(vertexAttributeID);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colorVBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(colours), colours, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glVertexAttribPointer(colourAttributeID, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(colourAttributeID);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glBindVertexArray(0);

    while (isAppRunning)
    {

        SDL_Event events;
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&events))
        {
            switch (events.type)
            {
                //close the window
            case SDL_QUIT:
            {
                isAppRunning = false;
                break;
            }
            }
        }

        glClearColor(191 / 255.0f, 87 / 255.0f, 205 / 255.0f, 255 / 255.0f);

        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        glBindVertexArray(VAO);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
        glBindVertexArray(0);

        SDL_GL_SwapWindow(window);
    }

    glDeleteBuffers(1, &EBO);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &colorVBO);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &vertexVBO);
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &VAO);

    glDisableVertexAttribArray(colourAttributeID);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(vertexAttributeID);

    shader.Destroy();

    Shader::Shutdown();

    SDL_GL_DeleteContext(context);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit;

    return 0;
}
```

Shader.cpp

```
#include "Header Files/Shader.h"

GLint Shader::vertexShaderID = 0;
GLint Shader::fragmentShaderID = 0;

bool Shader::Initialize()
{
    vertexShaderID = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);

    if (vertexShaderID == 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Error! Vertex Shader could not be created! This could be because of your Graphics Card not supporting modern OpenGL!" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    fragmentShaderID = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    if (fragmentShaderID == 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Error! Fragment Shader could not be created! This could be because of your Graphics Card not supporting modern OpenGL!" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

void Shader::Shutdown()
{
    glDeleteShader(vertexShaderID);
    glDeleteShader(fragmentShaderID);
}

GLuint Shader::GetUniformID(const std::string& uniform) const
{
    auto ID = glGetUniformLocation(programID, uniform.c_str());
    assert(ID != -1);
    return ID;
}

GLuint Shader::GetAttributeID(const std::string& attribute) const
{
    auto ID = glGetAttribLocation(programID, attribute.c_str());
    assert(ID != -1);
    return ID;
}


bool Shader::Create(const std::string& vertexShaderFilename, const std::string& fragmentShaderFilename)
{
    programID = glCreateProgram();

    if (programID == 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Error! Shader Program could not be created! This could be because of your Graphics Card not supporting modern OpenGL!" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    if (!CompileShaders(vertexShaderFilename))
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (!CompileShaders(fragmentShaderFilename))
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (!LinkProgram())
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

bool Shader::SendData(const std::string& uniform, GLint data)
{
    glUniform1i(GetUniformID(uniform), data);
    return true;
}

bool Shader::SendData(const std::string& uniform, GLuint data)
{
    glUniform1ui(GetUniformID(uniform), data);
    return true;
}

bool Shader::SendData(const std::string& uniform, GLfloat data)
{
    glUniform1f(GetUniformID(uniform), data);
    return true;
}

bool Shader::SendData(const std::string& uniform, GLfloat x, GLfloat y)
{
    glUniform2f(GetUniformID(uniform), x, y);
    return true;
}

bool Shader::SendData(const std::string& uniform, GLfloat x, GLfloat y, GLfloat z)
{
    glUniform3f(GetUniformID(uniform), x, y, z);
    return true;
}

bool Shader::SendData(const std::string& uniform, GLfloat x, GLfloat y, GLfloat z, GLfloat w)
{
    glUniform4f(GetUniformID(uniform), x, y, z, w);
    return true;
}

void Shader::Use() const
{
    glUseProgram(programID);
}

void Shader::Destroy() const
{
    glDeleteProgram(programID);
}

bool Shader::LinkProgram()
{
    glAttachShader(programID, vertexShaderID);
    glAttachShader(programID, fragmentShaderID);
    glLinkProgram(programID);
    glDetachShader(programID, vertexShaderID);
    glDetachShader(programID, fragmentShaderID);

    GLint linkResult = 0;

    glGetProgramiv(programID, GL_LINK_STATUS, &linkResult);

    if (linkResult == GL_FALSE)
    {
        GLchar error[1000];
        GLsizei bufferSize = 1000;

        glGetProgramInfoLog(programID, bufferSize, &bufferSize, error);

        std::cout << "Error! Program did not link successfully! Error information down below: " << std::endl;
        std::cout << error << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    std::cout << "Program Linked Successfully!" << std::endl;

    return true;
}

bool Shader::CompileShaders(const std::string& filename)
{

    std::ifstream file(filename);

    //file.open(filename);

    if (!file)
    {
        std::cout << "Error opening \"" + (filename)+"\"! File non - existent or unreachable! Make sure to check the spelling or the path!" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    std::string line;
    std::string sourceCode;

    while (!file.eof())
    {
        std::getline(file, line);
        sourceCode += line + "\n";
    }

    //file.close();

    auto shaderID = (filename.find(".vert")) ? vertexShaderID : fragmentShaderID;

    const GLchar* finalCode = reinterpret_cast<const GLchar*>(sourceCode.c_str());

    //bind shader code with object
    glShaderSource(shaderID, 1, &finalCode, nullptr);

    //compile shader code
    glCompileShader(shaderID);

    GLint compileResult;

    glGetShaderiv(shaderID, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &compileResult);

    if (compileResult == GL_FALSE)
    {
        GLchar error[1000];
        GLsizei bufferSize = 1000;

        glGetShaderInfoLog(shaderID, bufferSize, &bufferSize, error);

        std::cout << "Error! Shader did not compile successfully! Error information down below: " << std::endl;

        std::cout << error << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    std::cout << "Shader compiled successfully!" << std::endl;

    return true;
}
```

Shader.h

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <assert.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include "gl.h"

class Shader
{
public:

    static bool Initialize();

    static void Shutdown();

    GLuint GetUniformID(const std::string& uniform) const;
    GLuint GetAttributeID(const std::string& attribute) const;

    bool Create(const std::string& vertexShaderFilename, const std::string& fragmentShaderFilename);

    bool SendData(const std::string& uniform, GLint data);
    bool SendData(const std::string& uniform, GLuint data);
    bool SendData(const std::string& uniform, GLfloat data);

    bool SendData(const std::string& uniform, GLfloat x, GLfloat y);
    bool SendData(const std::string& uniform, GLfloat x, GLfloat y, GLfloat z);
    bool SendData(const std::string& uniform, GLfloat x, GLfloat y, GLfloat z, GLfloat w);

    void Use() const;
    void Destroy() const;


private:

    static GLint vertexShaderID;
    static GLint fragmentShaderID;

    GLuint programID{ 0 };

    bool LinkProgram();

    bool CompileShaders(const std::string& filename);
};
```

Shader.vert

```
#version 460

in vec3 vertexIn;
in vec3 colorIn;
out vec3 colorOut;

void main(void)
{
    colorOut = colorIn;
    gl_Position = vec4(vertexIn, 1.0);
}
```

Shader.frag

```
#version 460

in vec3 colorOut;
out vec4 pixelColor;

void main(void)
{
    pixelColor = vec4(colorOut, 1.0);
}
```

Comment: When I run the code, the assert on the shader file activates, saying that the ID of the attribute id is -1, however, on my log, it says that the shader file has been correctly loaded and linked. Is there anything else I can do to make it reproducible or show how it happens on my screen?

Comment: Yes, the only other shader files there are RGB.vert and RGB.frag, which the program should not select.

Comment: Yes, but the files I'm using are the Shader.vert and Shader.frag, whose code is represented up there. I've made sure to save them after editing, and even after closing and reopening the file, it stays the same.

Comment: Just checked and the file path is correct, here's a screenshot of my console log printing the shader code. https://pasteboard.co/66j3N4G9Awz1.png

Comment: ...the shader files are normal ASCII files right?  Nothing funky like UTF-8 + BOM or UCS-2?

Comment: The files are encoded in UTF-8

Comment: Next step is to switch to [raw string literals](https://github.com/genpfault/glfw-mcve-base/blob/master/src/main.cpp#L28-L54) for the shader strings; that should factor out any filesystem weirdness, as well as make the MCVE more self-contained.

Comment: I am not sure how it could be related, but you have no active context (`SDL_GL_MakeCurrent`). `glUseProgram` will generate an error if the program could not be made part of current state. `glGetAttribLocation` only requires a successful linking. So, i would say, at some point you will need an active context, ...

Comment: Since you're targeting OpenGL 4.6, you may be better off using explicit attribute locations (`layout(location=...)`) rather than querying them with `glGetAttribLocation`.